# Is there any way to cast Fn(& mut Type) -> _ to Fn(&mut dyn trait) -> _?

Tags: rust

Cast `Fn(& mut A) -> _` to `Fn(&mut dyn Paint) -> _`
and that `A` is already impl `Paint`

```rust
use std::{sync::{Arc, Mutex}, thread, time::Duration};

trait Paint: Send + 'static {
    fn paint(&mut self, c: &mut Canvas);
}

struct A(());
impl A { fn nexta(&mut self) {} }
impl Paint for A {
    fn paint(&mut self, c: &mut Canvas) {}
}
struct B(());
impl B { fn nextb(&mut self) {} }
impl Paint for B {
    fn paint(&mut self, c: &mut Canvas) {}
}

struct Obj {
    obj: Box<dyn Paint>,
    f: Box<dyn FnMut(&mut dyn Paint) + Send + 'static>
}

impl Obj {
    fn apply(&mut self) { (self.f)(&mut *self.obj); }

    fn paint(&self, canvas: &mut Canvas) { canvas.paint(&*self.obj); }
}

struct Canvas {}

impl Canvas {
    fn new() -> Self { Self {} }
    fn paint(&mut self, obj: &dyn Paint) {}
}

struct Anime {
    canvas: Arc<Mutex<Canvas>>,
    objs: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Obj>>>,
}

impl Anime {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            canvas: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Canvas::new())),
            objs: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new())),
        }
    }

    fn push<T, F>(&mut self, obj: T, mut f: F)
    where
        T: Paint,
        F: FnMut(&mut dyn Paint) + Send + 'static
    {
        let mut objs = self.objs.lock().unwrap();
        objs.push(Obj {
            obj: Box::new(obj),
            f: Box::new(f)
        });
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        let objs = Arc::clone(&self.objs);
        let canvas = Arc::clone(&self.canvas);
        thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let mut objs = objs.lock().unwrap();
            let mut canvas = canvas.lock().unwrap();
            for obj in &mut *objs {
                obj.apply();
                obj.paint(&mut canvas);
            }
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        });
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut anime = Anime::new();
    // i want don't change this
    anime.push(A(()), move |a: &mut A| a.nexta());
}
```

I want to know is there any way to solve it? Or any dynamic dispatch way?

Comment: How would that work? The `Fn(&mut A)` can't handle any `&mut dyn Paint`, but that's what the second function signature promises.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance

Comment: The code compiles, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Note that assuming you don't need to `run()` twice, you can avoid the `Arc<Mutex>`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in general convert from `FnMut(&mut T)` to `FnMut(&mut dyn Paint)` since you can pass to the second things that are not `T`, and it needs to be ready to handle them.

In your case, this will never happen, since you control what gets passed to it. But the compiler does not know that. It is possible to "fix" that with downcasting, but that requires `'static`, dynamic checks, and `unwrap()`. There is a better way.

The proper fix is to add a level of indirection. The problem arises from the fact that in `Obj`, we store two objects, `obj` and `f`. Those two objects have a correlation (`f` can only take `typeof(obj)`), but since we use `dyn Trait`, the compiler cannot know that.

The fix is to operate statically on `T: Paint`. Then, after we have an object which only accepts one `T`, we can use dynamic dispatch on this whole object.

Code is worth thousand words:

```rust
struct Obj<T, F> {
    obj: T,
    f: F,
}

trait ObjTrait {
    fn apply(&mut self);
    fn paint(&self, canvas: &mut Canvas);
}

impl<T, F> ObjTrait for Obj<T, F>
where
    T: Paint,
    F: FnMut(&mut T),
{
    fn apply(&mut self) {
        (self.f)(&mut self.obj);
    }

    fn paint(&self, canvas: &mut Canvas) {
        canvas.paint(&self.obj);
    }
}

struct Anime {
    canvas: Arc<Mutex<Canvas>>,
    objs: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Box<dyn ObjTrait + Send>>>>,
}

impl Anime {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            canvas: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Canvas::new())),
            objs: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new())),
        }
    }

    fn push<T, F>(&mut self, obj: T, mut f: F)
    where
        T: Paint,
        F: FnMut(&mut T) + Send + 'static,
    {
        let mut objs = self.objs.lock().unwrap();
        objs.push(Box::new(Obj { obj, f }));
    }

    // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9479f1a3730339ad79f7f0961418d740).

This is even more efficient, since we allocate once and not twice.

Comment: thanks, it's helpful. before this i use unsafe to convert that xd